# Chrome now adds a right-margin to background-images of a table-cell

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Here's a code snippet of the issue (use Chrome, and press Run after the page loads; I don't need to do this when it's on any other page). You'll see the first boxes are flush with eachother, but the second boxes have a gap. The only difference is the second boxes are within a div that has an auto margin.

This same code has worked for me for years, but in a Chrome update in the last few months, it suddenly adds this transparent border that the background-image cannot fill. But a background color can fill it!

```css
  td:first-child {
      background:red url(https://d11wkw82a69pyn.cloudfront.net/siteassets/images/test-automation/canvas/1440x950_canvas_test_automation.jpg);width:20px;
    }
    td:last-child {
      width:20px;background:blue
    }
    tr {
      height:20px;
    }
```

```html
   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
    <div style="width:500px;margin:0 auto">
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm struggling to see how this isn't the expected behavior. There is no margin on the second set of boxes, you have set the table's width to 500px so it's less wide than the table above, if you remove this but keep the auto margin it's the same as above, hence `The only difference is the second boxes are within a div that has an auto margin` is just plain wrong.

Comment: I saw the code snippet above in a separate jsfiddle page, didn't see it wasn't showing there. The issue in question only displays when a fractional pixel is introduced, and that depends on the size of the screen. As it's being included in an iframe, you can show the issue I'm talking about by looking for class 'snippet-result-code' on this page, and giving it a width of 102%. I've found an interim fix in the mean-time before Chrome addresses the issue though. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out why it's happening. It's related to fractional pixels. These occur if a percentage is used, or margin: auto. In both scenarios, the position of the table is at X.Ypx, and now introduces the gap in painting to the right of background-images in table-cells.  A very silly and annoying bug for Chrome to introduce; I hope they fix it.  I've had to put an interim fix in, by center positioning with javascript, with a rounded pixel value.

NB: The code snippet above only shows the issue when a fractional pixel is introduced, so it usually depends on the size of the screen. As it's being included in an iframe, you can show the issue I'm talking about by looking for class 'snippet-result-code' on this page, and giving it a width of 102%.

Answer (score 0):

You can add more css:

```html
table {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I would opt for `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left`